# select data from 2 tables using composite key

Tags: sql

```
create table emp
(
    eid integer primary key,
    ename varchar(25),
    age int,
    salary float
)

create table works
(
    eid int foreign key references emp,
    did Char(12) foreign key references dept,
    pct_time int,
    primary key(eid, did)
)

create table dept
(
    did char(12) primary key,
    budget float,
    managerId int foreign key references emp
)
```

I want to select ename from emp that who works in both 'itsd' and 'academic' departments.

Comment: i want to select ename from emp that who works in both 'itsd' and 'academic' departments

Comment: Where is itsd  .

Comment: its in column did in works table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to join the tables, filter for the departments, aggregate and check, that the number of departments is 2 (which are distinct, because of the primary key constraint).

```
SELECT e.ename
       FROM emp e
            INNER JOIN works w
                       ON w.eid = e.eid
       WHERE w.did IN ('itsd', 'academic')
       GROUP BY e.ename
       HAVING count(*) = 2;
```

Another option is using `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT e.ename
       FROM emp e
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM works w
                            WHERE w.eid = e.eid
                                  AND w.did = 'itsd')
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM works w
                                WHERE w.eid = e.eid
                                      AND w.did = 'academic');
```

Comment: what is the different having count(w.did)=2 and  having count( distinct w.did)=2

Comment: Thank you. both queries are works

Comment: distinct isn't needed since eid, did is primary key

Comment: @udaraNadeeshani: If you have three three rows for example and the values `'a'`, `'b'` and `'a'` in a column `col`, `count(col)` returns `3`, but `count(DISTINCT col)` returns two, as there are only two different values. If you have two entries with `'itsd'` for an employee but none with `'academic'`, `count(did)` would return `2`, that is selecting that employee, though they don't work in `'academic'`. `count(DISTINCT did)` fixes that.

Comment: @udaraNadeeshani: But Turo is right, it doesn't matter here because of the primary key constraint. I edited the answer and removed it.

Comment: thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Join with the work table, select only this two departments and check if the ename exists twice:

```
select ename from emp join works on emp.eid = works.eid
 where did in ('itsd','academic')
 group by ename having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: its work. thank you. can you explain having count(*) = 2 this part

Comment: You get 1 row for each match with the works table. By limiting to the departmenst itsd and academic, each ename can appear once, if the ename is in itsd or academic, not at all if  has none of both and twice if in both of them, so count(*) = 2

Comment: i got it thank you